# Eigenvalues - Identity Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm currently doing reading into calculating the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a $3\times3$ matrix and come across the following confusion:

In one of the resources that I'm using, it gives the identity matrix has this:

$$I = \begin{bmatrix}
 \lambda& 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & \lambda & 0\\ 
 0& 0& \lambda  
\end{bmatrix}$$

But in most cases, and, in the original definition the identity matrix has $1$'s down the diagonal line where everything else is $0$'s.

I know that $\lambda$ is a scalar value, and therefore would it be correct to assume that: $\lambda = 1$?

Therefore, suppose that I have this matrix:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
 1 & -1 & 3\\ 
 4& 5& 10  
\end{bmatrix}$$

Can I therefore subtract each of the elements in $A$ by the expression that $\lambda = 1$? If this is wrong, how am I missing the point of what the $\lambda$ representations within the identity matrix?

Comment: I think it is just a typo. That matrix is $\lambda I$.

Comment: That matrix is $\lambda I$, not $I$. Where did you see this?

Comment: @M.Vinay Maybe I have interpreted it wrong. I'm following from: [link](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate_bases/eigen_everything/v/linear-algebra--eigenvalues-of-a-3x3-matrix).. So how do I calculate $\lambda I$?

Comment: It's written $\lambda I$ all over the place. If it's written as $I$ in just one instance, it's a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

As other commenters have observed you have written the matrix $\lambda I$.  This is useful because you will want to compute $A-\lambda I$ to find eigensystems.  I.e., with your given $A$, 
$$ A - \lambda I = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 10 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1-\lambda & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & -1-\lambda & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 10-\lambda \end{bmatrix} $$

To find eigenvalues, we want $\det(A - \lambda I)$.
\begin{align} \det(A - \lambda I) &
= \det \begin{bmatrix} 1-\lambda & 2 & 1 \\ 1 & -1-\lambda & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 10-\lambda \end{bmatrix} \\
&= (1-\lambda)(15-(-1-\lambda)(10-\lambda) ) - 2((10-\lambda)-12) + 1(5 - 4(-1-\lambda) \\
&= -12 + 22\lambda + 10 \lambda^2 - \lambda^3
\end{align}
Setting this last polynomial equal to zero, $0 = -12 + 22\lambda + 10 \lambda^2 - \lambda^3$ and finding its roots, we get three horrible expressions which can be evaluated to give values near $0.455, -2.236, 11.78$.  These three horrible expressions are the eigenvalues of your $A$ (and are approximated by the values given).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I'm still not getting what the value of $\lambda$ would be? When looking at your example..?

Comment: $\lambda$ is a parameter.  To find eigenvalues, take the determinant of the matrix on the right in my answer, yielding a polynomial in $\lambda$.  Set that polynomial equal to zero and solve for the roots, i.e., solve for the values of $\lambda$ that make the "equal to zero" true.

Comment: I think I get it. The determinant will tell you a number.. Let's say, it's 27.. Then you can find all the factors of 27 and see which ones gives a determinant of 0 and thus implies that it's an eigenvalue? BUT, if you're finding the determinant of the matrix on the right, how would you find the root? What would therefore be: $1 -\lambda$ if its a parameter? Sorry I'm really trying to learn this. I think I get it though so thanks

Comment: Er..., no.  Your description lacks a polynomial.  The determinant will provide a polynomial.  I will extend my answer...